# Prove that if $m$ is a positive integer and $x$ is a real number...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Q: Prove that if $m$ is a positive integer and $x$ is a real number, then**

$$
\lfloor mx \rfloor=\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{1}{m} \rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{2}{m} \rfloor+...+\lfloor x+\frac{m-1}{m} \rfloor. 
$$

Let $x=n+\frac{r}{m}+c$, where n is an integer, r is a nonnegative integer less than m, and c is a real number with $0\le c<\frac{1}{m}$.

If we substitute this x to $\lfloor mx \rfloor$, we get

$\lfloor mx \rfloor=\lfloor m(n+\frac{r}{m}+c) \rfloor=\lfloor mn+r+mc \rfloor$.

Because $c<\frac{1}{m},$ $mc$ is smaller than 1. Hence, $\lfloor mn+r+mc \rfloor=mn+r.$

Moving on to the next function, we get

$\lfloor x+\frac{1}{m}  \rfloor =  \lfloor n+\frac{r}{m}+c+\frac{1}{m} \rfloor=\lfloor n+\frac{r+1}{m}+c \rfloor$.

$\lfloor x+\frac{2}{m}  \rfloor =  \lfloor n+\frac{r}{m}+c+\frac{2}{m} \rfloor=\lfloor n+\frac{r+2}{m}+c \rfloor$.

...

$\lfloor x+\frac{m-1}{m}  \rfloor =  \lfloor n+\frac{r}{m}+c+\frac{m-1}{m} \rfloor=\lfloor n+\frac{m+r-1}{m}+c \rfloor$.

In order to solve this countably infinite functions, we have to split them into two groups. The first group owns functions that $ \frac{r}{m}+c+\frac{y}{m}<1,$ so $\lfloor x+\frac{y}{m} \rfloor=n.$

Second group contains functions that $ \frac{r}{m}+c+\frac{y}{m} \ge 1,$ so $\lfloor x+\frac{y}{m} \rfloor=n+1.$

Then, we have to know where the number starts to become 1. We can notice this by:

$ \frac{r+y}{m}+c = 1$

$r+y=m(1-c)$

$y=m(1-c)-r$

Hence, we now know that

$\lfloor x+\frac{m(1-c)-r}{m} \rfloor=\lfloor n+1 \rfloor=n+1.$

Therefore, from $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to $\lfloor x+\frac{m(1-c)-r-1}{m} \rfloor$, all the values are n. From $\lfloor x+\frac{m(1-c)-r}{m} \rfloor$ to $\lfloor x+\frac{m-1}{m} \rfloor$, all the values are n+1.

But then I am stuck at this part. I have no idea how to move on to the next step to solve this question.

Please Help Me!!

Comment: How is this question related to the [former one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763974/prove-that-if-m-is-a-positive-integer-and-x-is-a-real-number-then)?

Comment: For the former one, I was asking whether the answer is correct or not. In this post, I was stuck on the solution.

Comment: There is no "countably infinite functions" here. You have a **finite** list of applications of the floor function.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are $m$ terms in any series from $0$ to $m-1$, you have that $$\begin{align}
\lfloor mx\rfloor&=(m-k)\times n+k\times (n+1) \\
&=mn+k
\end{align}$$
You have only to prove that $k=r$. You will see that $k$ can be determined as follows.
$$\begin{align}
k&=\lfloor (m-1)-(m(1-c)-r-1)\rfloor \\
&=\lfloor m-1-m+mc+r+1\rfloor \\
&=\lfloor mc+r\rfloor
\end{align}$$
And since $c<\frac{1}{m}$, $mc<1$. So, $k=\lfloor mc+r \rfloor = r$.

Answer (score 0):

I totally understood this question.

From $\lfloor x+\frac{(1-c)m-r}{m} \rfloor$, the value becomes $n+1$.

Hence, the number of $n$ is

$m(1-c)-r=m-mc-r$. Because the number of n has to be an integer and $mc<1$, it becomes: $m-r$.

The number of $n+1$ is

$(m-1)-(m(1-c)-r-1)=(n+1)(mc+r)$.

Following the exact same logic that is explained above, we get: $mc+r=r$.

Thus, if we add them together,

$n(m-r)+(n+1)r=mn-nr+nr+r=mn+r$

Hence, proved.

Comment: I think you probably do understand the proof. Unfortunately, you have not conveyed that understanding into the words and symbols in this answer.

Comment: Which part did you not understand?

Comment: I think I understand everything you meant to write. Certainly I can guess what you *should* have been thinking at each step. The problem is that you didn't write the proof. What you wrote is full of errors, such as claiming that "the number of $n$ is" a non-integer. Oh, later you say it has to be an integer, which is true, but in the meantime you have literally said it was not. Then you write the gem $mc + r = r$, also obviously false. You could fix most of what's wrong with this by adding a few $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ brackets in the right places.

Comment: "From _______, the value becomes _____" in a properly written proof would literally mean that whatever you wrote in the first blank is the reason why some (previously mentioned) quantity has the value you write in the second blank. Again, I hope that's not what you actually meant to write. What I think you meant to write would have looked more like, "From _______ to _______, the value is ______."